# Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException : could not find driver laravel postgresql

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I just started helping out on a new project. They are using laravel 5.8 with postgresql. I've only worked with laravel 7 and 8 so I've never seen this error before. I've tried many of the fixes on this site but haven't gotten it to work. When I run php artisan serve I get the error below. First I listed the software I'm using and the project is build on.

Mac - running catalina
Apache2 - xampp shows it as stopped and I cannot get it to run
Postgresql v
laravel 8 is installed on my computer but the app is running 5.8

Then I've ran the following and done the following fixes.

1. brew install postgres

- then I checked the install with brew services list and brew services start postgresql
  composer require doctrine/dbal

2. changed the php.ini file (all the help files say there are two but I can only find one under my xampp - apache folder) and uncommented

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll  
;extension=php_ming.dll 
;extension=php_mssql.dll    
;extension=php_mysql.dll    
;extension=php_mysqli.dll   
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client 
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11g Instant Client   
;extension=php_openssl.dll  
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll 
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll    
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll    
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll  
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll 
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll <----
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll   
extension=php_pgsql.dll <-----
```

3. Ran docker-compose exec service php -m but it says "docker-composer" command not found

error

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException  : could not find driver

  at /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31
    27|             parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
    28|             $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, [PDOStatement::class, []]);
    29|             $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    30|         } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
  > 31|             throw new PDOException($exception);
    32|         }
    33|     }
    34| 
    35|     /**

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27

  2   PDO::__construct("pgsql:host=ec2-44-196-146-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com;dbname=db216s9bl09spg;port=5432;sslmode=prefer", "vjdnxozbwomqce", "51f3f1e4c3583774e733127f0fbc9aa6eff079372adaf54856e876413e485a91", [])
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27

  3   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::__construct("pgsql:host=ec2-44-196-146-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com;dbname=db216s9bl09spg;port=5432;sslmode=prefer", "vjdnxozbwomqce", "51f3f1e4c3583774e733127f0fbc9aa6eff079372adaf54856e876413e485a91", [])
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:67

  4   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createPdoConnection("pgsql:host=ec2-44-196-146-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com;dbname=db216s9bl09spg;port=5432;sslmode=prefer", "vjdnxozbwomqce", "51f3f1e4c3583774e733127f0fbc9aa6eff079372adaf54856e876413e485a91", [])
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:46

  5   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createConnection("pgsql:host=ec2-44-196-146-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com;dbname=db216s9bl09spg;port=5432;sslmode=prefer", [])
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/PostgresConnector.php:33

  6   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\PostgresConnector::connect()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:182

  7   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:918

  8   call_user_func(Object(Closure))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:918

  9   Illuminate\Database\Connection::getPdo()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:901

  10  Illuminate\Database\Connection::getDoctrineConnection()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:887

  11  Illuminate\Database\Connection::getDoctrineSchemaManager()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/phaza/laravel-postgis/src/PostgisConnection.php:10

  12  Phaza\LaravelPostgis\PostgisConnection::__construct(Object(Closure), "db216s9bl09spg", "")
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/phaza/laravel-postgis/src/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:23

  13  Phaza\LaravelPostgis\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::createConnection("pgsql", Object(Closure), "db216s9bl09spg", "")
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:76

  14  Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::createSingleConnection()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:50

  15  Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::make("pgsql")
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:131

  16  Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager::makeConnection("pgsql")
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:86

  17  Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager::connection("pgsql")
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:199

  18  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository::getConnection()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:167

  19  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository::repositoryExists()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:583

  20  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::repositoryExists()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:91

  21  Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand::prepareDatabase()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:63

  22  Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand::handle()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:32

  23  call_user_func_array([])
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:32

  24  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:90

  25  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:34

  26  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:576

  27  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:183

  28  Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255

  29  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:170

  30  Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:921

  31  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:273

  32  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149

  33  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:90

  34  Illuminate\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:133

  35  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Users/djkinjo/Documents/CasaCoding_Projects/mhs-america-2019/artisan:37
```

I'm not sure if the issue is with Apache or my postgresql setup.
Thanks is advance!

Comment: Why are you using `XAMPP` if you have `docker` ? Fully switching to `docker` would fix your problem.

Comment: I don't have docker installed.... or is that part of the doctrine folder?

Comment: Docker is a complete VM sort of solution, it is the most used and if you want to be professional, you will have to learn it, so it would help you a lot. No more XAMPP or similar

Comment: Oh ok! I will go look up the docs. But regarding this failure, do you think its a server issue or something with my setup?

Comment: I think it is related to your local, as you are using XAMPP, I did not use it in a very long time, so I have no idea how is the current state of it. But I am 100% sure it is related to that.

Comment: hmm I see. Thanks for the guidance. So, your recommendation would be just to uninstall xampp? I don't think I'm really using it these days since almost everything I code is laravel 8 now lol

Comment: Yes ! Personal recommendation would be to create your own `docker-compose` file and have there `PHP` (surely 8), `MySQL` or your desired DB, `apache` or `nginx` so you can access the container via web, and if you want you can also add `Redis` for cache if you need it. There are plenty of good tutorials out there that can help you achieve this.

Comment: could it be that I need to install php 5.6?

Comment: I don't think so, but install whatever version is supported on `composer.json`.